# SQL SUM giving 2 rows. I want 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having difficulty in getting this query to return the sum in 1 row.

```
SELECTst.[code], SUM(whst.WHQtyOnHand)
FROM dbo.[StkItem] st, dbo.WhseStk whst
WHERE whst.WHWhseID in (3, 4) 
    AND whst.WHStockLink = st.StockLink 
    AND st.Code = 'BNV203N'
GROUP BY st.[Code], whst.WHWhseID, whst.WHStockLink
```

Here is the result I get:

```
Code        WHQtyOnHand
---------------------------
BNV203N        694
BNV203N       3748
```

I need them as a total.

Comment: Does this even work on sql server

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @Mihai it works on sql server.  marc_s thanks for the input, have changed to join as per Rich Benner's solution below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just want to group by `st.Code`. I'd also get out of the habit of that cartesian `join` and `where` clause. Just use a proper `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT st.[code], SUM(whst.WHQtyOnHand)
FROM dbo.[StkItem] st
INNER JOIN dbo.WhseStk whst 
    ON whst.WHStockLink = st.StockLink
WHERE whst.WHWhseID IN (3,4)
    AND st.Code = 'BNV203N'
GROUP BY st.[Code]
```

Comment: upvoted for advising proper (non-prehistoric) `join` syntax

Comment: Thanks for the extra advice on the joins @Rich

Answer (score 4):

Change this line:

```
GROUP BY st.[Code], whst.WHWhseID, whst.WHStockLink
```

to

```
GROUP BY st.[Code]
```

When you group by WHWhseID, you break out those rows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Rocky. I am changing my accepted answer to Rich Benners below as he did provide extra advice with using joins. You still have my upvote :)